# How to replace values using a logical vector in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using `dplyr` and `tidyr` to clean and organize my dataset. `dplyr` doesn't take a logical vector, so I'd like to know if there is a workaround. Here is the data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = as.Date(c("6/19/2020", "6/22/2020", "6/23/2020", "6/25/2020", "6/26/2020", "6/26/2020"),format = "%m/%d/%y"), 
                      DueDay = c(3L,2L,1L,4L,3L,4L)),
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

If `Date == "Friday"` and `DueDay == 3`, then replace `DueDay` from `3` to `1`.

The result should look like this:

```
    Date        DueDay
1   2020-06-19  1
2   2020-06-22  2
3   2020-06-23  1
4   2020-06-25  4
5   2020-06-26  1
6   2020-06-26  4
```

`weekdays(df1$Date) == "Friday"` gives a list of logical values, but how can I incorporate it into the codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifelse()` can also work:

```
df1 %>% mutate(DueDay = ifelse(weekdays(Date)== "Friday" & DueDay == 3, 1,DueDay)) -> df1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `format` with `%A`to extract the full 'weekday' name from the `Date` class column 'DueDay', construct a logical vector in `replace` and change the values of 'DayDay' that meets the condition to 1

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(DueDay = replace(DueDay, format(Date, "%A")== "Friday" & DueDay == 3, 1))
#          Date DueDay
#1 2020-06-19      1
#2 2020-06-22      2
#3 2020-06-23      1
#4 2020-06-25      4
#5 2020-06-26      1
#6 2020-06-26      4
```

---

Or using `case_when`

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(DueDay = case_when(format(Date, "%A")== "Friday" &
                DueDay == 3 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ DueDay))
#         Date DueDay
#1 2020-06-19      1
#2 2020-06-22      2
#3 2020-06-23      1
#4 2020-06-25      4
#5 2020-06-26      1
#6 2020-06-26      4
```

---

Or more compactly in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[format(Date, "%A") == "Friday" & DueDay == 3, DueDay := 1]
```

---

Or using an index in `base R`

```
i1 <- with(df1, format(Date, "%A")== "Friday" & DueDay == 3)
df1$DueDay[i1] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `weekdays`.

```
res <- within(df1, DueDay[weekdays(Date) == "Friday" & DueDay == 3] <- 1)
res
#         Date DueDay
# 1 2020-06-19      1
# 2 2020-06-22      2
# 3 2020-06-23      1
# 4 2020-06-25      4
# 5 2020-06-26      1
# 6 2020-06-26      4
```